# Why does using bootstrap change css layout?

Tags: css, progress-bar, bootstrap-modal

I am using the [Bootstrap Progress Bars](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp). Here is my code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:1%">
      1%
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It changes the display output of the website. Do you know why is that? I use WordPress.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The style.css file in my theme already contains reset code. Is there a way to turnoff the reset in bootstrap?

Comment: I think no, that's why Bootstrap is hated by anyone else but Back-End developers when it comes to custom styles.

Comment: If it's hated by everyone else, then why is it so popular? Apparently frontend devs should love it enough, or else it wouldn't have been born at the first place

Comment: Based on my experience as a fullstack, I've worked with fe and be only, so they have a completely different opinion about it. As be you just dont care as long its working, but as fe you have to make it nice and pleasant - and there is the problem.

Comment: It exploded in popularity because you can scaffold website interfaces with 0 effort, you just c&p html file and don't have to understand it. But if you want to make custom changes - it kills you neurons :)

Comment: Haha :D. Yes, please make it an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap css file, contains a `reset` which enforces all elements to look the same on all browsers.

Therefore, if bootstrap.css is included after your .css, it will cause a global overwrite of your .css; if bootstrap.css is included before your .css, it will result in broken bootstrap UI if you are also using some kind of reset.

Here can be found more about Reset: https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/

My suggestion is that if you have more than 30% custom styles, switch to something else away from bootstrap, e.g. tailwindcss.

If you have like >50% custom styles, then use Sass which is a neat way to write css.

---

May the bugs avoid you, Eugene.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the pros and cons of Bootstrap?

Comment: Pros and Cons are very opinionated and compared to something, so, I suggest that you just google this question.